# Empty SET statement (with no SET option assignments) is allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The MS documentation about [differences Between Compatibility Level 80 and Level 90 is telling on Compatibility Level 80](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510680(v=sql.105)#remarks), "Empty SET statement (with no SET option assignments) is allowed."
What is Empty SET statement (with no SET option assignments) ?
Please give me example to clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be very old behavior and the only thing I have found is from some German [forum](https://www.berndjungbluth.de/2008/08/13/von-80-nach-90-empty-set-statement/):

> In SQL Server 2000, the list of deprecated features in SQL Server 2005
>   has compatibility level 80 with the entry "Empty SET statement (with
>   no SET option assignments) is allowed." and compatibility level 90
>   with "Empty SET clause." is not allowed. ".
>
> But what is an Empty SET statement?
>
> My first thought was a SET statement without any further assignment.
>   But actually this idea was too suspicious for me, because what brings
>   a SET statement without assignment?
>
> Only after some research I found something. In fact, it is possible in
>   SQL Server 2000 to simply place a SET in an SP - without any
>   assignment.
>
> There is also a somewhat strange syntax that is used - for whatever
>   reason:
>
> ```
> DECLARE @CustomerId As nchar (5) 
> SET SELECT @CustomerId = 'ALFKI'
> SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
> ```
>
> I do not even want to think about the sense and nonsense of the SET
>   SELECT statement. The fact is that SQL Server generates 2 statements
>   (SET and SELECT) out of it. And a SET statement without assignment is
>   no longer possible with SQL Server 2005.

As soon as nothing like this exists, you are save to change the compatibility level.